# What's the correct way to enforce constraints on case class values

Tags: scala

Throwing exceptions at construction time is generally seen as not a very polite thing to do, but I'm not sure how to avoid that when trying to enforce constraints on case class values.

Say for example that I need to represent a range, and that both boundaries must be positive. An immediate implementation would be:

```
case class Range(from: Int, to: Int)
```

This, however, does not make sure that both `from` and `to` are positive, nor that `to` is greater than `from`.

My first instinct is to implement it as follows:

```
case class Range(from: Int, to: Int) {
  require(from >= 0)
  require(to >= 0)
  require(to >= from)
}
```

This, however, makes `Range`'s constructor unsafe.

Is there a common pattern to keep the ease of use of case classes, enforce value constraints, and avoid throwing exceptions?

Comment: "enforce value constraints, and avoid throwing exceptions?" - what do you mean by enforce? What do you want to happen when someone tries to construct a Range with invalid from/to?

Comment: Thanks Paul, that's the crux of my question. What *should* I do? I'm trying to prevent the creation of invalid instances, and there seems to be a consensus that constructors or construction methods should not throw. I don't know how to do one without the other, is there a solution that I'm not seeing?

Comment: The idealistic answer is type-level programming (but steep learning curve). It should be a compile-time error to create such a thing. However, without that, you seem to have four choices: ignore the problem (accept invalid parameters), throw an exception, force the parameters to valid ranges, mark the instance as invalid with a flag (and throw exceptions when any method is called on it?). Me, I'd throw an exception in the constructor...

Comment: "mark the instance as invalid with a flag (and throw exceptions when any method is called on it?)." - a variant of this: return an InvalidRange subclass (or object) of Range that errors on everything.

Comment: I like your last suggestion a lot, it's clean and type-safe and everything. It just conflicts with my deeply ingrained "fail-fast" reflex, where if I know something that shouldn't happen has happened, I should fail immediately rather than try and return a (probably incorrect) result anyway.

Comment: Right. The best place to fail is compile-time. After that, constructor (IMO  - if you can't construct a useful instance, you should fail). Note if you had a concept of PositiveInts in your program, and make range take a start:PositiveInt, length:PositiveInt, it wouldn't be possible to construct an invalid range...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is pretty subjective, but I'll try.

It depends on how your class is constructed. In the case of a simple utility range class used casually in internal code, any programmer using it should probably be aware that feeding a range wrong values might lead to weird results. You can assume that sane uses of the classes really don't encounter this problem, and throwing an exception in these rare cases might not be a bad practice to signal somebody really screwed up. If it is obvious from context what values should be fed to the class or not, I don't think it is particularly in bad taste to throw exceptions if people fail to meet these expectations of sanity.

Compare this to the behaviour of `NullPointerException`s or `ArithmethicException`s which still happen within Scala sometimes. Sometimes it just isn't reasonable anymore to program defensively when faced with enough 'insanity'.

On the other hand, if your class is filled by values you have less control over, i.e. they are the direct consequence of user input, you have to simply take greater control over your construction. Create a companion object with a function that returns an `Option` or an `Either`:

```
 object Range {
     def createSafe(from: Int, to: Int): Option[Range] = {
         if(from >= 0 && to >= 0 && to >= from)
            Some(Range(from, to))
         else
            None
     }
 }
```

You can then even reuse the validation logic in the instantiation of your case class by overriding `apply` as the other answer suggested.

```
 object Range {
    def createSafe ...
    def apply(from: Int, to: Int): Range = {
        createSafe(from, to).getOrElse(throw new IllegalArgumentException(...))
    }
 }
```

Comment: Please note that there is probably an infinite recursion in my answer (`apply` calls `createSafe` which calls `apply` which...), but you get my drift.

Answer (score 6):

You can overload the `apply` operator in the companion object to achieve what you'd like to do:

```
object Range{
  def apply(from: Int, to: Int) ={
    val _from = Math.max(0, from)
    val _to = Math.max(0, to)
    if(_from < _to) new Range(_from, _to)
    else new Range(_to, _from)
  }
}
```

Do note that using `to` as a variable name can lead to some "interesting" results.

Comment: Although my suggestion to use type programming is a more general skill worth learning, this suggestion will be far easier to implement for this particular case. :)

Comment: Just to make sure I understand this correctly: it's considered more desirable to coerce invalid input to valid one than to fail? For example, `Range(-1, -20)` should return `Range(1, 20)`, even though we know with absolute certainty that it's not what the caller wanted (regardless of whether what he wanted was possible or not)?

Comment: @wheaties I find strange to assume that this solution is wanted. I would have also taken the path of `require`. Why should I alter parameters?

Comment: @Kigyo He mentioned he would rather not throw exceptions, so I built that into my answer. Normally, I'd just throw exceptions myself using a `require` but sometimes it is better to have an "empty" result than an invalid one.

Comment: @wheaties I see. I almost feared that you would give me a reason to change my past written code, where I used `require` from time to time. :)